# Can I download firebase database json

Tags: android, json, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Can we download firebase database json through android application if yes how can we do that. I can do it manually from Firebase console. I want to know how can I do it programmatically through android application

Comment: Hey @UmairIqb , this is the same problem currently I'm facing. Did you got proper solution. I'm new to android and can't understand Frank's answer. Could you please share the solution.

Comment: you have to download firebase data in hashmap type as it is store in the database and then you can convert it into json

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to read the entire contents of the Firebase Database without using the Firebase SDK, you can do so with its [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data).

To do so, use the URL that you can see in your Firebase console and then by adding `.json` to the end. So for example, `https://yourproject.firebaseio.com/.json`.

Comment: Iam creating an application usin firebase realtime database in which user store and retrieve information.Now I want on a button click user can able to download its information from firebase database in json format.Is it possible?

Comment: Yes. If you want a direct export, you'd use the REST API as mentioned. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data. You'll have to authenticate their requests yourself in that case though, which the SDK would usually do for you behind the scenes. So definitely consider if it isn't easier for you to just reconstruct the download data on the client from the `DataSnapshot`s you already have.